# Error al sincronizar modelo en mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Quiero sincronizar mi modelo en `mysql workbench`y me aparece este error:

> Fetching table list.
>       0 items from dbEncuesta OK Fetching view list.
>       0 items from dbEncuesta OK Fetching routine list. Operation failed: Table 'proc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Answer (score 0):

Intenta reparar la tabla que te da el fallo,esto lo puedes hacer con

```
REPAIR TABLE proc;
```

Recuerda hacer una copia de seguridad de la tabla antes de repararla, ya que la reparación puede causar pérdida de datos.